# Help determining what is injecting broken code into my website

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, error

On my website, I log client-side errors. Recently, a number of my users have been experiencing the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
```

and the "file" in which this occurs is:

```
data:application/javascript;base64,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
```

The interesting thing is that I don't use any base-64 encoded scripts at all. If you base64-decode and pretty-print the above blob, you get:

```
var urchinTracker = function() {},
    _gaq = {
        push: function() {
            try {
                if (arguments[0][0] == '_link') window.location.href = arguments[0][1]
            } catch (er) {}
        }
    },
    _gat = {
        _createTracker: function() {},
        _getTracker: function() {
            return {
                __noSuchMethod__: function() {},
                _link: function(o) {
                    if (o) location.href = o;
                },
                _linkByPost: function() {
                    return true;
                },
                _getLinkerUrl: function(o) {
                    return o;
                },
                _trackEvent: function() {}
            }
        }
    };
cxApi = {
    setCookiePath: function() {},
    chooseVariation: function() {}
}
var _gat = {
    _getTrackerByName: function() {
        _trackEvent: function() {}
    }
};
```

This looks vaguely like Google Analytics code, and I do indeed use Google Analytics. But I also imagine that this is unlikely to be something Google Analytics is doing itself, because I generally expect Google products not to barf errors.

Has anyone seen this before / know what it is?

Comment: Looks like a page hijacking script.  The section "window.location.href = arguments[0][1]" will redirect the user somewhere.  It _may_ be deliberately designed to look like analytics to confuse/fool people.

Comment: I think this could be very old Google analytics tracking code since it contains the word urchinTracker which was the first version og GA. They based it on the Urchin tracker. However I can't validate nor cofirm the validity of the code you show us here. But maybe this can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's one of the privacy-protecting extensions (Privacy Badger / Ghostery / etc.) injecting it to disable Google Analytics by replacing its methods with stubs.